# hasMany() associations can not be define in Squelize.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

This is the teacher Table's Schema

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../util/databaseConnection');


const Teacher = sequelize.define("teacher", {
 teacherid: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
},
surname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
},
firstname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
},
lastname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
}

})


module.exports = Teacher;
```

This is the subject Model's Schema

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = require('../util/databaseConnection');


const Subject = sequelize.define('subject', {
    subjectid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        AutoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    subjectname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    grade: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    subjectinfo: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }

})

module.exports = Subject;
```

I need to define the association between teacher hasMany subject

```
Teacher.hasMany(Subject)
```

But following error

> Naming collision between attribute 'subjects' and association
> 'subjects' on model teacher. To remedy this, change either foreignKey
> or as in your association definition

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Following keys

```
Teacher.hasMany(Subject, { foreignKey: 'teacher_id', targetKey: 'id' });
```

and in Subject model add following column

```
    teacher_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {         
            model: 'teacher',
            key: 'id'
        }   
    },
```

Comment: can you plz describe what is the issue with my model?